# Zend hidden elements: hide html values

Tags: forms, zend-framework, decorator, hidden

I am facing a special scenario here on some of my forms.
I have settled a permission system over some fields many of which are required.
When removing the permission to view the field on a form, I set:

$field->setDecorators('disableLoadDefaultDecorators', true);

The problem in that case is that I get prompted with the validation error over the required field, which is logical.

The other option would be to set the $field to hidden but the issue turns to become an html problem where any person can retrieve the hidden value through the source code.

Hopefully someone can offer me a suggestion on how to hide the element from the form and metadata but return it on form validation as if it was displayed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change the field validation rules so that it is not required:

```
$field->setRequired(false)->setDecorators('disableLoadDefaultDecorators', true);
```

Comment: Nop! this cant work as the required field are notnull in the db and have constraints rules over them and thus can not be returned empty. What I really need is a kind of decorator that disables the field in a way it would return its value.

Comment: Then you have to change it to hidden. (Btw you shouldn't absolutely trust on hidden data. You have to make all checks server side as well to make sure someone is not sending you raw post data)